# Рекурсия + cUrl

Tags: php, ооп

Извиняюсь за непонятный заголовок, так как не знаю как правильно назвать эту проблему.

Есть класс, в котором реализована авторизация и получение данных из другого сайта.
При вызове метода `get_histroy` мы должны получить данные с сайта, будучи авторизованными. Если мы не авторизованы, то вызываем метод `auth`, который проходит авторизацию и после этого снова вызываем метод `get_histroy` что бы получить данные.

```
class TestClass{

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $login = "";
private $password = "";
private $phone = "";
private $url = "https://test.ru/";

private $curl = "";
public $cookie_file = 'cookie.txt';


function __construct($login, $password, $phone)
{
    $this->login = $login;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->phone = $phone;
    $this->curl = curl_init();
}

/**
 * @name Authorization
 */
private function auth()
{
    $url_auth = "https://auth.test.ru/auth?retpath=https://mail.test.ru";
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $post_login = "login=".$this->login."&passwd=".$this->password;
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_auth);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_login);
    curl_exec($this->curl);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->cookie_file); // записываем файл с куками
}

/**
 * @param bool $format
 * @return array|mixed|null|object
 */
public function get_histroy($format = false)
{
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
    $html = curl_exec($this->curl);
    $result_history = json_decode($html);
    var_dump($result_history);

    // если мы авторизованы
    if(isset($result_history -> success) && $result_history -> success == "1"){

        /**
         * @return json || array
         */
        if($format == false) return $result_history;
        else return json_decode($html, true);

    } else{ // если не авторизованы

        self::auth(); // проходим авторизацию
        self::get_histroy($format); // запускаем функцию заново

    }
}

function __destruct()
{
    curl_close($this->curl);
}

}
```

Вызов:

```
$object = new TestClass("admin", "pass", "+38000000000");
print_r($object ->get_histroy());
```

Проблема в том, что после авторизации метод не дает нам полученные данные, хотя авторизация проходит нормально. Если вставить `var_dump($result_history);` как в примере, то данные показываются, а вот из экземпляра класса он не выводится. Только если перезагрузить страницу, то все работает (уже будучи авторизованным).

Старался изложить проблему понятливее.

Comment: Вместо `self::auth(); self::get_histroy($format);` попробуйте написать `$this->auth(); $this->get_histroy($format);`.

Comment: `self::` это обращение к статичным функциям, которые не используют `$this` и класс не объявлен через `new`, а у вас в классе есть `$this` и функции не статичные(одна зависит от другой), поэтому `self` использовать не нужно.

Comment: @mix к сожалению все так же.

Comment: @mix думал может файл куков не успевает создаться, поставил sleep(2); но результат тот же.

Answer (score 2):

Решено:

```
return $this->get_histroy($format); // запускаем функцию заново и возвращаем результат (return)
```

Нужно было вернуть то что вернула функция.